# Policy on boosting tag-count for points

Tags: discussion

I have spotted this recently, and have been suspicious in the past that it may be taking place. That is, someone submitting an answer and then adding more tags to the question.

Importantly, I am not talking about improving the question, but adding unnecessary tags, purely to increase the number of them.

- Is there some mod-system or procedure in place to help recognise such
  behaviour?
- Alternatively, should we be reporting this behaviour? Unfortunately,
  it is a very difficult thing to spot.

I work hard to edit and improve questions and am disappointed if others consider this an acceptable practice.

Comment: Can you give an example of an "unnecessary" tag? Often the person answering the question has the most knowledge of the topic and is able to add relevant tags that are missing.

Comment: For example, there is already an `ms-access` tag and someone adds `ms-access-2010` leaving the other four that are already there.

Comment: Hard to tell without context. But if the question turns out to be specific to `ms-access-2010`, then I wouldn't consider that abusive.

Comment: Somewhat related: [What is considered incorrect tagging?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176318/what-is-considered-incorrect-tagging)

Comment: That link has this quote `No, you should not add tags that are a superset of the question.`. That relates to the policy of tagging, and is understood (I hope). It is the potential for abuse that concerns me.

Comment: @Mysticial Yes, that was a trivial example. I will exaggerate a little to emphasize the point, and suggest that there might be a question specifically for JS and someone adds unrelated tags for HTML, CSS (and perhaps CSS3).

Comment: Filler tags are among some of my most hated things.